# How to group together same user id but with order by time?

Tags: mysql

```
imei        date
10013700    6:00:00 AM
10015700    6:00:00 AM
10014200    6:00:01 AM
10014500    6:00:04 AM
10016300    6:00:04 AM
16014600    6:00:04 AM
10013700    6:00:05 AM
10015700    6:00:05 AM
10013000    6:00:06 AM
10014700    6:00:06 AM
10016300    6:00:06 AM
10016300    6:00:06 AM
```

This is table that consists of imei and time.. now i need to make table by date and group by imei...

```
imei        date
10013700    6:00:00 AM
10013700    6:00:05 AM
10015700    6:00:00 AM
10015700    6:00:05 AM
10014200    6:00:01 AM
10014500    6:00:04 AM
10016300    6:00:04 AM
10016300    6:00:06 AM
10016300    6:00:07 AM
16014600    6:00:04 AM
10013000    6:00:06 AM
10014700    6:00:06 AM
```

i have started from initial time and grouped by imei together with time and start with other imei number next to start time of previous imei in my data set along with imei,date there are other attributes..

```
con = sqlite3.connect("E://code/differenttaxi.sqlite")
df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM taxitable WHERE date>="2013-12-16      06:00:00" AND date<"2013-12-17 00:00:00" JOIN (SELECT id,imei, i,lat,lon,speed,direction,error,engine,meter,min(date) first from taxitable group by 10013700)on imei=i ORDER BY first',con)


df.to_csv('E:\\code\\Query_Result.csv',index=False)
con.close()
print("completed!\n")
display(pd.read_csv('E:\\code\\Query_Result.csv'))
```

Error generated:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 
>   near "JOIN": syntax error

Comment: @HimalAcharya Don't post code in comments, edit the question and add it nicely to the end.

Comment: Looks like you just need to `ORDER BY user, date`. No `GROUP BY` needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the *first* date for each user and order by that:

```
select t.user, t.date
from mytable t
join (select user u, min(date) first from mytable group by 1) x
  on user = u
order by first, user, date
```

Comment: Does it give an error? If so, what error? If not, what does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: @himal I think I know where I went wrong - I didn't specify enough in the order by clause. try edited answer

Comment: Finally this worked
SELECT t.imei,t.date FROM taxitable t JOIN (SELECT imei i,min(date) first from taxitable t group by imei) \
                   on imei=i\
                    ORDER BY imei,first

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl.user, tbl.date FROM table_name tbl
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user, date FROM table_name GROUP BY user
) ord on tbl.user = ord.user
order by ord.date, tbl.date
```